# Does DataGrip Support Postgres Authentication with Kerberos?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, active-directory, kerberos, datagrip

I have been looking everyone online and cannot find the answer to this question. Several different Postgres IDEs allow you to connect to your AWS Postgres server using Kerberos/AD authentication. I cannot find any documentation saying whether DataGrip supports that authentication and connection method, although I am seeing a reference to a Kerberos Server option when trying to create the connection.

Server is in AWS, we have Kerberos/AD auth setup for the server. I can connect to the server using Kerberos with other IDEs but am comparing different IDEs and want to see if DataGrip can work for this scenario. So does DataGrip have a way to use Kerberos/AD authentication to connect to remote servers?

I have tried creating a Postgres data source connection using DataGrip with our AWS host URL in a way similar to how other IDEs allow me to connect, but I see no way to specify the use of Kerberos/AD authentication. I am unable to connect to our AWS Postgres server using DataGrip at the moment since the server/database is expecting all connections to use Kerberos/AD.

Comment: You might get a better response at: [DataGrip – IDEs Support (IntelliJ Platform) | JetBrains](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200381555-DataGrip)

Answer (score 0):

Create a config file in /etc/jaas.conf:

```
pgjdbc {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useTicketCache=true
debug=true
renewTGT=true
doNotPrompt=true;
};
```

Add the following parameter to VM options:

```
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=/etc/jaas.conf
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is on the right track for us, but I'm still getting a GSS connection error when trying to use this: "GSS Authentication Failed".  But at least it seems to be accessing the server in the first place, it wasn't doing that before. Do you have any further tips based on that GSS error?

Comment: datagrip doesn't support kerberos auth for postgresql :'(

Comment: Please report your issue on our tracker https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue and include the idea log from Help - Show Log in Files when posting your issue. We'll investigate it.